# How to make 3 boxes like this screenshot has?

Tags: plugins

I am trying to create the 3 boxes that appear right below navigation and the email sign-up form. Is there a plugin to create something like that? Or what is a possible way to accomplish this sort of thing?

[image]

Here is what I tried to do for posting the meta box, but it didn't show up.

[image]

Also there is a calendar widget. But that isn't showing up either. Would you know why?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please **edit your question** to include your current code, and any issues/problems you've encountered with your implementation attempt. Please note that **plugin recommendations** are off-topic for WPSE.

Comment: @ChipBennett thanks for your answer. In this case, I am just trying to understand how to create this kind of an effect. I have the basic twenty-ten theme and it doesn't have an option to create boxes like that...so I am wondering what is the right way to do this.

Comment: If you're talking about the boxes are the bottom of the image, You can achieve this by metaboxes or widgets. Everything else can be achieved via templating - so you should start your research there

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I just tried to add a meta box, but it didn't quite work. I'll post a screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is far too broad; you need to look at the CSS and HTML source and theme that site is based on to find out how that layout is done. Look at other free WP themes to find a similar layout.

And learn how to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see the CSS and HTML of that site and the site you're trying to develop.

Comment: @songdogcoach it looks like regular html once I looked at it. Now I am trying to figure out how to do this with meta boxes as Howdy_mcGee suggested :)

Comment: @Genadinik You'll need to do some template editing - I don't think by default the twenty-ten theme supports boxes on the front page. It might be best to find a theme that shows what you want - download it, then open its template files and reverse engineer how they do it. Either way you're gonna have to do some real research.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you might be looking for widgets. Here is what I'm using on my theme.

The first thing to do is to register your widgets

```
function sidebars_register() {

        $mws = array (
            'sidebar-3' => array (   
                __( 'Header Widget One', 'pietergoosen' ) => __( 'Header widgets for homepage', 'pietergoosen' ),
            ),
            'sidebar-4' => array (   
                __( 'Header Widget Two', 'pietergoosen' ) => __( 'Header widgets for homepage', 'pietergoosen' ),
            ),
            'sidebar-5' => array (  
                __( 'Header Widget Three', 'pietergoosen' ) => __( 'Header widgets for homepage', 'pietergoosen' ),
            ),
            'sidebar-6' => array (  
                __( 'Header Widget Four', 'pietergoosen' ) => __( 'Header widgets for homepage', 'pietergoosen' ),
            ),
        );

        foreach ( $mws as $mi => $mw ) {
            foreach ($mw as $mwn => $mwd) {
                register_sidebar(
                    array (
                        'name'          =>  $mwn,
                        'id'            =>  $mi,
                        'description'   =>  $mwd,
                        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
                        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
                        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sidebars_register' );
```

I'm using four header widgets, you can use only three.

Next, create a template and call it `sidebar-header.php` Add the following code in there. This will set up your css classes

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header Sidebar. Shows only on homepage.
 *
 */
function pietergoosen_header_widget_class() {
    $count = 0;

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) )
        $count++;

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ) )
        $count++;

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ) )
        $count++;

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' ) )
        $count++;   

    $class = '';

    switch ( $count ) {
        case '1':
            $class = 'one';
            break;
        case '2':
            $class = 'two';
            break;
        case '3':
            $class = 'three';
            break;
        case '4':
            $class = 'four';
            break;  
    }

    if ( $class )
        echo 'class="' . $class . '"';
}

if (   ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3'  )
    && ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' )
    && ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-5'  )
    && ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-6'  )
)
    return;

?>
    <div id="headerwidget" <?php pietergoosen_header_widget_class(); ?>>

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="first" class="header-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #First .widget-area -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="second" class="header-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #Second .widget-area -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="third" class="header-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #Third .widget-area -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="forth" class="header-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #Fourth .widget-area -->
    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- #Header widgets -->
```

You can now call this in your header or in the appropriate template like this. I'm using mine in `header.php` just before the `<body>` tag. Mine is also conditional, it only loads on the homepage. You can just modify it

```
<? if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>  
        <?php get_sidebar( 'header' ) ?>
    <?php endif ; ?>
```

Lastly is your css. This is how mine looks like to get it to show perfectly

```
#headerwidget { 
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 1420px;
        display: block;
        float: center;
        padding: 15px 30px 0;
    }

    /* One Widget Area */
    .one .widget-area {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* Two Widget Areas */
    .two .widget-area {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        width: 48.5%;
    }
    .two .widget-area + .widget-area {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    /* Three Widget Areas */
    .three .widget-area{
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        width: 31.3%;
    }
    .three .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    /* Four Widget Areas */
    .four .widget-area {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
        width: 23%;
    }
    .four .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

You should be able to modify this into a working three widget layout. I've given you the base to work from here. Good Luck!